# notificationBuilder.setSound() to ringtone does not work

Tags: android, push-notification, ringtonemanager

I use below code :

```
Uri idUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
notificationBuilder.setSound(idUri);
```

After receive notification, not playing `RINGTONE type`. Playing `ALARM type`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using mp3 in res folder try like this :

```
notificationBuilder.setSound(Uri.parse("uri://sadfasdfasdf.mp3"));
```

Else you can use default tone,

```
Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
notificationBuilder.setSound(uri);
```

Comment: I want use default tone, but TYPE_RINGTONE not work.

Comment: Try this, `if (idUri == null) {
            idUri = 
         RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
        }
        Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, idUri);
        ringtone.play();`

Comment: I dont want use ringtone.play(); i want set into notification sound